# Invoking a Process/Batch to execute with elevated rights

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, svn, wmi

We have a subversion system up and runnuing at a central server. At the moment I can access that svn repository over a network share. As this is not good practice I will close that network share and will access my svn only over the "svn" command (I use TortoiseSVN Client for that).

As new Projects will be started in the future, me and my fellow colleagues must be able to create new repositorys on that server. For the creation you would need write-rights on that server directory, but I don't want that. Also I don't want to run to our Admin every time (all this is ok with our admin and I have his support).

First, my idea: Trigger a process on the server which will create the Repository. But here I am stuck with how to trigger a process if I am not the server admin (tried a WMI VB Script) So here would be the question, how to elevate the rights of the caller during the script execution? I do not want to store the admin password in plain text in a script or batch file.

Second, can this be done in some other forms? how do you guys create your repositorys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there is no way of auto-elevation in CMD. The only way to do that I can think of is to use the windows schduler. You could write a bat file that executes all the commands you need. Then create a task with the scheduler and tell it to run the bat file. During the creation leave the "Triggers" section empty, check the "run with highest privileges" box, enter a user account that has the rights you need and enter the password. Then go to "Settings" and check the "Allow task to be run on demand" box.

Now the second part (**OPTIONAL**). Adept the user policy on the server so that the users you want to be able to execute the process are allowed to trigger scheduled tasks on the server. You could also enter the users PCs as "trusted" on your server. There are several ways to achieve that. However, afterwards the users must be able to execute scheduled tasks on the server.

Now you are done! If you've done the optional section your users can trigger the task with `SCHTASKS /RUN /S <RemoteServerName> /TN "<task name>"`. No stored credentials needed and the script runs with elevetad rights.

If you didn't use `SCHTASKS /RUN /S <RemoteServerName> /U username /P password /TN "<task name>"`.

Comment: That sounds very good! Have to discuss that with my admin. Do you see some elegant way to pass at least one argument to that schtask-runned-batch from the triggering user? (like the repository name)

Comment: Not, this is not possible. The Windows security policy disallows that because this would be a big security leak. Imagine a task that is running with admin permissions and takes a command line as agument. Something like `SCHTASKS /RUN /S <RemoteServerName> /TN "<task name>" /param "CMD /c format C: /y"` ;-). You could try `SCHTASKS /Change ...` to adept your task before execution but I haven't tried this before.

Comment: No problem, i'll make that work somehow. Got some Ideas for it.